# pandas want to calculate percentage between two different data use dic

Tags: python, pandas

```
dt=df['dt'] 
first=df['first']
x=pd.value_counts(pd.to_datetime(df.dt.sum()).strftime('%Y-%m'))
y=pd.value_counts(pd.to_datetime(first.sum()).strftime('%Y-%m'))

x                    y
2015-01 111          2015-01  654
2015-03 1231         2015-03  315
2015-05 123          2015-05  464
2015-02 456          2015-02 654
.                    .
.                    .
```

x and y is having a data like this

ie) 2015-01 =(654/111)*100

i wnat to calculate like same year-month x,y  (x/y)*100

```
  y         x
((2015-01+2015-02)/2015-02)*100
((2015-01+2015-02+2015-03)/2015-03)*100

2015-02=(654+654/456)*100
2015-03=(654+654+315/1231)*100
like this


I want to put this x and y in dictionary
date is key and number is value

ie) dict={2105-01:111,2015-03:1231......}
```

Comment: `(x/y)*100` does not work?

Comment: `2015-01 =(654/111)*100 ` is correct?

Comment: Can you add output of `2015-02=(654+654/456)*100
2015-03=(654+654+315/1231)*100` ?

Comment: Or better what are values in dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) + [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) + [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) + [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) (for remove first value) + [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
#last value is incorrect, because 2015-04 is not in sample
d = y.sort_index().cumsum().div(x).mul(100).iloc[1:].to_dict()
print (d)
{'2015-02': 286.84210526315786, 
 '2015-05': 1696.747967479675, 
 '2015-03': 131.84402924451666}
```

Comment: how to put x in dict?

Comment: Try `d=x.to_dict()`